# Help interpret this stack trace

Tags: c++, stack-trace

I know that it fails at strcmp. I've provided operator< below, which calls strcmp.

On line #1 there's the value @0xbfffeeac. What does the @ mean?

```
#0  0x00212bd8 in strcmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0012ed2f in Json::Value::CZString::operator< (this=0x8317300, other=@0xbfffeeac)
    at src/lib_json/json_value.cpp:221
#2  0x001361b0 in std::less<Json::Value::CZString>::operator() (this=0x83173a0, __x=@0x8317300, 
    __y=@0xbfffeeac)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/stl_function.h:230
#3  0x00136101 in std::_Rb_tree<Json::Value::CZString, std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value> >, std::less<Json::Value::CZString>, std::allocator<std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value> > >::_M_lower_bound (this=0x83173a0, 
    __x=0x83172f0, __y=0x83173a4, __k=@0xbfffeeac)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/stl_tree.h:986
#4  0x001348da in std::_Rb_tree<Json::Value::CZString, std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value> >, std::less<Json::Value::CZString>, std::allocator<std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value> > >::find (this=0x83173a0, __k=@0xbfffeeac)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/stl_tree.h:1421
#5  0x0013383a in std::map<Json::Value::CZString, Json::Value, std::less<Json::Value::CZString>, std::allocator<std::pair<Json::Value::CZString const, Json::Value> > >::find (this=0x83173a0, __x=@0xbfffeeac)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/bits/stl_map.h:659
#6  0x00131779 in Json::Value::operator[] (this=0x8317280, key=0xbfffef74 "col1")
    at src/lib_json/json_value.cpp:1055
#7  0x00131ba8 in Json::Value::isMember (this=0x8317280, key=0xbfffef74 "col1")
    at src/lib_json/json_value.cpp:1169
#8  0x0805cf4d in CFG::CFG_Fetch_Raw (this=0x825846c, section=0x8317280, key=0xbfffef74 "col1", defval=0x0)
    at CFG.cpp:48
#9  0x08050e5b in Generic::CFGSetup (this=0x825846c, k=0x8255e2c "display_qt") at Generic.cpp:89
#10 0x0804df6a in LCDControl::ConfigSetup (this=0xbffff2a8) at LCDControl.cpp:81
#11 0x0804d93b in LCDControl::Start (this=0xbffff2a8, argc=1, argv=0xbffff404) at LCDControl.cpp:15
#12 0x0804f224 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff404) at Main.cpp:7

bool
Value::CZString::operator<( const CZString &other ) const
{
   if ( cstr_ )
      return strcmp( cstr_, other.cstr_ ) < 0; //src/lib_json/json_value.cpp:221
   return index_ < other.index_;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking `this->cstr_` for null, but you're not checking `other.cstr_`.  Perhaps the container prevents any strings with null `cstr_` values from being inserted, so such a check is not necessary.

That's not the problem, however, since other is not null in this case.  Rather it looks like the `other` object may have been deleted.  How are you managing the lifetimes of the objects in the `std::map` container?  Is it possible that one of the values was deleted without being removed from the map?

Update:

On further inspection, this seems to be the key:

```
#5  0x0013383a in std::map<...>::find (this=0x83173a0, __x=@0xbfffeeac)
#6  0x00131779 in Json::Value::operator[] (this=0x8317280, key=0xbfffef74 "col1")
```

You're passing in a constant string pointer (0xbfffef74, which is obviously valid since the debugger displays the string), and it's being automatically converted into a temporary value of type `CZString`.  You can see that the temporary `CZString` object is faithfully passed all the way down to the `operator<`.

I believe that the `0x8...` addresses indicate heap allocations, while `0xbf...` addresses indicate stack allocations.

Unfortunately, what we need to see is the arguments to `strcmp()`.  We need to know if, when `CZString::operator<` was called with an "other" argument of `0xbfffeeac` (the temporary `CZString` object), whether it passed the original string value of `0xbfffef74` into `strcmp`, or perhaps a heap-allocated copy of that string (I don't know what CZString does internally).

If this is the first comparison in the b-tree search, that probably indicates that the second argument to `strcmp` was not correctly converted to a `CZString`.  Otherwise, it indicates that the second argument is being passed down correctly, and one of the strings in your map is invalid but not null, leaving "deleted" and "not null-terminated" as likely suspects.

Comment: @Scott Actually I accidentally submitted before I was done answering.  I don't think that the null check (or lack thereof) has anything to do with *this* problem, only that it might be *a* problem.

Comment: Well, I just sent an email out to jsoncpp's mailing list about it pointing out what you stated at first. I'll follow up with your other comments.

Comment: I tried to provide libc's debug info. I made sure glib-debuginfo and glibc-debuginfo-common were installed before launching gdb for the provided stack trace. They were already installed.

Comment: I found the problem. I freed a pointer in the wrong scope. The index of col tipped me off. It should have been col0.

Answer (score 1):

@0xbfffeeac looks like a special value, maybe uninitialized memory ? I am just guessing, but could the @ symbol be put there to indicate the memory address points to a specially formatted value to indicate uninitialized memory ?

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking. I'm not sure what it means. I'll have to search the GDB docs.

Comment: I believe that the `@` indicates that the parameter is a reference to the given address, rather than a pointer.

Comment: interesting, if you google @0xbfffeeac, you get alot of hits from people observing this address when their software crashed.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` symbol denotes that the parameter was passed by reference.

For help understanding the memory map of your program, e.g. what addresses are in a data segment versus on the stack, try `info files` under gdb.  Also, since you're running under Linux, check out the output of `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `strcmp` is receiving unexpected values at run-time, or something. Just an idea, sorry if I'm wrong.